Detach tabs with PyQt5 - keeping all widgets into the detached tabs
With a PyQt application, I wanted to deliver detachable tabs where user can by a double click detach a tab and reattach it to the main window by closing the detached tab.
I have minimize the problem to the following script that almost works except that when I have multiple QWidgets in the layout, only 1 on 2 is added to the detached layout. This is very puzzling.
Here is the code:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel, QStatusBar
)

# Variable to store detached windows
detached_windows = {}

def create_combined_tab():
    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    # Create two QLabel for demonstration
    label1 = QLabel("This is QLabel 1.")
    label1.setObjectName('label1')
    label2 = QLabel("This is QLabel 2.")
    label2.setObjectName('label2')
    label3 = QLabel("This is QLabel 3.")
    label3.setObjectName('label3')
    label4 = QLabel("This is QLabel 4.")
    label4.setObjectName('label4')
    label5 = QLabel("This is QLabel 5.")
    label5.setObjectName('label5')
    
    layout.addWidget(label1)
    layout.addWidget(label2)
    layout.addWidget(label3)
    layout.addWidget(label4)
    layout.addWidget(label5)

    widget.setLayout(layout)
    return widget

def detach_tab(tab_widget, index):
    """Detaches the tab and displays it in a new window."""
    tab_content = tab_widget.widget(index)
    tab_name = tab_widget.tabText(index)

    # Remove the tab from the QTabWidget
    tab_widget.removeTab(index)

    # Create a new window for the detached tab
    detached_window = QMainWindow()
    detached_window.setWindowTitle(tab_name)
    detached_window.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

    detached_content = QWidget()
    detached_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    detached_content.setLayout(detached_layout)

    # Move the content of the tab to the new window
    print(f"Before detaching: {tab_content.layout().count()} widgets")  # Debugging output

    for i in range(tab_content.layout().count()):
        item = tab_content.layout().itemAt(i)
        print(i, item)
        if item is not None and item.widget() is not None:
            widget = item.widget()
            detached_layout.addWidget(widget)  # Add the widget to the new layout

    print(f"After detaching: {detached_layout.count()} widgets in new layout")  # Debugging output

    detached_window.setCentralWidget(detached_content)
    detached_window.setStatusBar(QStatusBar())
    detached_window.statusBar().showMessage(f"{tab_name} - Ready")

    # Handle the close event of the detached window
    def on_close_event(event):
        tab_widget.addTab(detached_content, tab_name)  # Reattach the content
        tab_widget.setCurrentWidget(detached_content)  # Select the reattached tab
        event.accept()
        del detached_windows[tab_name]

    detached_window.closeEvent = on_close_event

    detached_window.show()  # Show the new window
    detached_windows[tab_name] = detached_window  # Keep track of the detached window

# Set up the application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = QMainWindow()
main_window.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

tabs = QTabWidget(main_window)
tabs.setMovable(True)

# Create and add the combined tab
combined_tab = create_combined_tab()
tabs.addTab(combined_tab, "Tab - QLabels")

# Connect the double-click event to detach the tab
tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(lambda index: detach_tab(tabs, index))

main_window.setCentralWidget(tabs)
main_window.setStatusBar(QStatusBar())
main_window.statusBar().showMessage("Application ready")

main_window.show()  # Show the main window
sys.exit(app.exec_())  # Start the application event loop



I don't understand why you create a new QWidget for the main window. Just take the widget of the tab and set it as central widget. Then use QMainWindow.takeCentralWidget() when you want to "reattach" it.

Also, some suggestions: 1. When using such an OOP oriented framework as PyQt (or PySide for what matters), you should opt for a more [sub]class based approach instead of one only based on functions (unless you are aware of its consequences); this also means that "global objects" should be avoided as well; 2. set object names only when necessary (don't try to mimic uic-generated scripts unless you know/understand what they do); 3. QMainWindow.statusBar() already creates one if none exists, there's no point in doing window.setStatusBar(QStatusBar()) followed by window.statusBar().

Many thanks for your suggestions. Indeed you are all right. No need to duplictate widgets inside the layout.  detached_window.setCentralWidget(tab_content)is the thing to do.
I have posted a code that does what I was looking for.

Here is an anwser with various contents in 3 tabs.
Many thanks to musicamante.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel, QStatusBar
)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Variable to store detached windows
detached_windows = {}

def create_label_tab(text):
    """Creates a tab with a QLabel."""
    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    
    # Create a QLabel with the provided text
    label = QLabel(text)
    layout.addWidget(label)

    widget.setLayout(layout)
    return widget

def create_matplotlib_tab():
    """Creates a tab with a Matplotlib plot."""
    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    # Create a Matplotlib figure and add a subplot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4, 9], label="Simple Curve")
    ax.legend()

    layout.addWidget(fig.canvas)

    widget.setLayout(layout)
    return widget

def create_combined_tab():
    """Creates a tab with a QLabel and a Matplotlib figure."""
    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    # Create a QLabel for demonstration
    combined_label = QLabel("This is a combined tab with QLabel and Matplotlib.")
    layout.addWidget(combined_label)

    # Create a Matplotlib figure and add a subplot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4, 9], label="Simple Curve")
    ax.legend()

    layout.addWidget(fig.canvas)

    widget.setLayout(layout)
    return widget

def detach_tab(tab_widget, index):
    """Detaches the tab and displays it in a new window."""
    tab_content = tab_widget.widget(index)
    tab_name = tab_widget.tabText(index)

    # Remove the tab from the QTabWidget
    tab_widget.removeTab(index)

    # Create a new window for the detached tab
    detached_window = QMainWindow()
    detached_window.setWindowTitle(tab_name)
    detached_window.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

    detached_window.setCentralWidget(tab_content)
    detached_window.statusBar().showMessage(f"{tab_name} - Ready")

    tab_content.show()  # Important: Ensure the widget is visible

    def on_close_event(event):
        # Take the widget back from the detached window
        reattached_content = detached_window.takeCentralWidget()
        tab_widget.addTab(reattached_content, tab_name)  # Reattach the content
        tab_widget.setCurrentWidget(reattached_content)  # Select the reattached tab
        del detached_windows[tab_name]  # Clean up

    detached_window.closeEvent = on_close_event

    detached_window.show()  # Show the new window
    detached_windows[tab_name] = detached_window  # Keep track of the detached window

# Set up the application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = QMainWindow()
main_window.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

tabs = QTabWidget(main_window)
tabs.setMovable(True)

# Create and add tabs
tab1 = create_label_tab("This is a simple QLabel tab.")
tab2 = create_matplotlib_tab()
tab3 = create_combined_tab()  # Combined tab with QLabel and Matplotlib

tabs.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1 - QLabel")
tabs.addTab(tab2, "Tab 2 - Matplotlib")
tabs.addTab(tab3, "Tab 3 - QLabel + Matplotlib")

# Connect the double-click event to detach the tab
tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(lambda index: detach_tab(tabs, index))

main_window.setCentralWidget(tabs)
main_window.setStatusBar(QStatusBar())
main_window.statusBar().showMessage("Application ready")

main_window.show()  # Show the main window
sys.exit(app.exec_())  # Start the application event loop



There should be no need to call setParent(), as tab_widget.addTab() will automatically take care of that. The close event is also accepted by default (as most standard events are), so there's no point in calling event.accept() too. OTOH, since this answer is not too different from your previous one and is also more appropriate, you should either edit the original one with the new solution (and then delete this), or delete the other instead, as there's little point in having two similar answers, especially if one is more reliable than the other.

You are right. Many thanks again for your insight on the proposed code.
